# Rally Analytics set the startindex for a query

Tags: rally

I have a query for the Rally Analytics which returns a data set larger than the pagesize. So I want to do another query to return the remainder data set.  I tried setting a startindex value but that does not work, StartIndex stays at 0.

```
                    this.query = {
                        find:Ext.encode(requestedQuery.find),
                        StartIndex:20000,
                        pagesize:20000 //MAX_PAGESIZE
                    };

                _queryAnalyticsApi:function () {
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url:"https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/1.27/" + this.workspace + "/artifact/snapshot/query.js?" + Ext.Object.toQueryString(this.query) +
                            "&fields=" + JSON.stringify(this.requestedFields) + "&sort={_ValidFrom:1}",
                        method:"GET",
                        //need to change this to a POST
                        success:function (response) {
                            this._afterQueryReturned(JSON.parse(response.responseText));
                        },
                        scope:this
                    });
                },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter you'll want to use is called start.  Also, on subsequent pages it is important to include a filter using the ETLDate returned from the first page of data so your results are consistent in time.  We have created a SnapshotStore in the AppSDK 2.0 that handles all this complexity for you.  Look for it soon!

Answer (score 1):

that works, it was confusing because the attribute of the result set is called StartIndex.  It would be nice if the granularity (i.e. day, week) could be defined and handled on the server first, so it wouldn't have to return such a large dataset.

Comment: I think the longterm vision for the Lookback API is to do some of these aggregations on the server for that exact reason.